# onItemClick ... passing the position in my array to somewhere else

Tags: android

Does the "`position`" parameter in the `onItemClick` reference the position in the `Adapter`, which might include, say, the footer and header as well. I'm asking because I want to be able to pass the actual position in the underlying array that I'm using with my `adapter`. Can I just pass "`position`" and I'll be good to go?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly the position is the position in your items array. Header and footer items I do not think get included, because your overridden method getPosition() simple returns the position you are seeking within the array of items.

Comment: Well Suri says the header and footer DO get included in the list position. What about using the id argument instead of position?

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your question, yes, headers and footers are included in the `position` parameter.

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) for onItemClick states the parameters are as follows:

> **parent**    The AdapterView where the click happened.
>
> **view**  The view within the AdapterView that was clicked (this will be a view provided by the adapter)
>
> **position**  The position of the view in the adapter.
>
> **id**   The row id of the item that was clicked.

So if you're looking to fetch an object from your underlying array, you should use the `long id` parameter instead, which returns the underlying array index:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    
    // Get the item that was clicked
    Object objectToUse = myAdapter.getItem( (int) id );
}
```